# Any rotation of a sphere $S^2$ resulting in two fixed points?

Tags: geometry, group-theory

Can anyone show why any rotation of a sphere
$S^2$ results in two fixed points? I am suddenly
getting confused why there would be two fixed
points.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_rotation_theorem

Comment: http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/22/1221.pdf

Comment: Think about the direction that the Earth rotates, and the North/South poles.

Comment: Every rotation in $R^3$ is rotation around some axis, and obviously the points where the axis intersects the sphere are fixed.

Comment: The two fixed points are the two unit vectors pointing at opposite directions on the rotation axis. Mathematically, they are the unit eigenvectors of the rotation matrix.

Comment: This proved first by Euler, and the proof cited by ''dato'' uses matrix theory. But (I heard) that Euler proved it without using matrices.